# Word for making something "as if it were real" when referring to a memory or fantasy

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word would mean *to figuratively bring to life* or to make something *as if it were real* in the context of a memory or fantasy?

For example, I am trying to figure out the word that would fill in the following sentences using the above description:

> Mark built his model town in order to [word for *to make as if it were real*] the fantasy he wished he could escape to.

and [possibly] alternately,

> Victims of traumatic experience will sometimes experience flashbacks, where the traumatic memories are [passive of the same word for *made-as-if-real*].

Comment: I think *realise* fits

Comment: ......flesh out

Comment: @mjsqu - realize would fit here if the fantasy actually became real. I was looking for a word that had the implication of making the fantasy "almost as if it was real" without implying that it actually became real.

Comment: What’s wrong with what you have already? Why must there be a single word for this?  Language is about stringing together individual words from a finite vocabulary to create infinitely many complex concepts.  This quixotic quest for single words to replace language is time better spent tilting at crossword puzzles.

Comment: _construct_ could be a good option too, similar to realise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many words that can be combined with others and used in the context you provided. here are some:

actualize- Make a reality of

materialize - Become actual fact; happen; appear in bodily or physical form

concrete- Make real or concrete instead of abstract

Express (something abstract) in a concrete form

Comment: I think the closest thing to what I was looking for was actualize

Answer (score 1):

Consider "[**conceptualize**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceptualize)."

> "Mark built his model town in order to **conceptualize** the fantasy he wished he could escape to."

Comment: Not exactly the connotation I was looking for. "Act out" gives the specific implication that he was taking the action of acting out the fantasy. I was looking more for a word that would mean "to make it real" in the figurative sense, but where the focus is on the bringing-to-life of the fantasy, rather that the action Mark takes to bring it to life. For example, had the fantasy  actually become real, "realise" would be the correct word. I'm looking for the word that would have the same meaning but where it comes to life figuratively instead of literally.

Comment: @Ephraim -- That's far too convoluted a meaning for any single word to be able to convey. You've restricted it so tightly that no word or expression will satisfy your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To **give life to a fantasy** or **create a fantasy** may be alternatives in your sentence, besides your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think **reify** would work. (It is similar to the word deify.)

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reify?s=t):

> reify
>   /ˈriːɪˌfaɪ/
>   verb -fies, -fying, -fied
>   1. (transitive) to consider or make (an abstract idea or concept) real or concrete

Answer (score 1):

The word *conjure* works in your first example, but not the second. In the first example the subject is manipulating reality in order to achieve a kind of intellectual alchemy. If you are searching for clinical meanings I might go a different way, but if the context is creative or dramatic, *conjure* works well.

*Mark built his model town in order to conjure an escape into fantasy.*

In the second example, I might re-engineer the sentence to say: "Victims of traumatic experience will sometimes experience vivid flashbacks, indistinguishable from reality.

I worked with a person who sometimes substituted the word *vivid* for *livid*, as in "He hung up on me and I was vivid!" Somehow it worked to project her meaning, and I held a wonderful image in my mind of her technicolor apoplexy.

Answer (score 0):

*Represent* was often employed this way in 20th-century LitCrit (usually, I seem to remember, translating or echoing German *vorstellen*), and both *imitate* and *imagine* were employed this way in older criticism.

But I'm not confident these uses would be transparent to lay audiences.

Answer (score -1):

Mark built his model town in order to **inchoate** the fantasy he wished he could escape to.

To [inchoate ideas, plans, attitudes etc are only just starting to develop](http://contemporary_en.enacademic.com/18830/inchoate)

Inchoating: inchoating
English Verb inchoating

```
Present participle of inchoate.
```

-wikipedia

Comment: *Inchoate* is an adjective, not a verb. Check your dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry, simply claiming that because Wikipedia says it is a verb, it is a verb --  when nobody actually uses it as a verb -- doesn't cut the mustard. Still not a verb.

Comment: "LlA — LEVEL INCHOATING A-ARM" -KLX-1789; preliminary hazards report to the Atomic ... text. Vitro Engineering Company.

Comment: "Upon the formation of the New Rite, General
Santa Anna, utterly undismayed by the silent rebuke
administered him by his brethren in inchoating the
Mexican National Rite and leaving him without its
pale..." -High lights of the Mexican revolution. Some previously ... . McLeish, John Lewin, 1871

Comment: "Let us write oftener, and longer,
and we shall not tempt the Fates by inchoating too long a
hope of letter-paper. I have written enough for one night:
I am now going to sit down and play one of Handel's Over-
tures as well as I can..." -The great English letter writers; with introductory ... v. 2. Dawson, W. J. ed. (William James), 1854-1928

Comment: So apparently a few individuals 100 years or more ago have used it as a verb; I thus concede that 'inchoate' has historically been used that way in a few very rare instances. But I continue to maintain that nobody currently uses it that way. A search of Google Books for 'inchoating' gave 241 results, with most dating from well before 1900, some being OCR transcription errors or 'lorem ipsum'-type text, some being history books that quote long-dead writers who once used it, and a few occurrences generated by non-native speakers. I couldn't identify a single credible instance of current usage.